# Find tuple of strings in string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

With the `startswith()` and `endswith()` functions it is possible to pass a tuple of strings, where if there is a match on any element the result is returned `True` e.g.,:

```
text_to_find = ("string_1", "string2")

test = "string_to_look_in"

if test.startswith(text_to_find ) == True:
     print  ("starts with one of the strings")
```

Is there a similar command, that will work with tuples, for finding a string in a string - i.e., one of the strings in the tuples appearing anywhere in the text. (instead of e.g., using a for loop, where individually look each item in the string).

Comment: I suggest `if any(x in test for x in text_to_find):`. There is no need for `== True` when testing a boolean condition.

Comment: @khelwood the "answer" is `if any(x in test for x in text_to_find)`

Comment: *"..one of the strings in the tuples appearing **anywhere** in the text.."*

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre You are quite correct. I didn't notice the "anywhere" part of the question until after posting my comment.

Comment: but you got the general idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, try using `any` to test all items in a list. Second, since you want to know if the string is contained anywhere in the text, you can use `in`. For example:

```
text_to_find = ("string_1", "string2", "to_look")

test = "string_to_look_in"

if any(s in test for s in text_to_find):
     print  ("contains one of the strings")
```