# How to check if string is in pymongo.collection.collection object

Tags: python, string, pymongo

I'm searching for a solution to this but could not find any practical one

lets say we have a `pymongo` `collection` string and we are searching for string named `"tk_dd_id"` in it.

```
collection =   Collection(Database(MongoClient(host=['123234'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True, ssl=True, replicaset='mongomongo'), 'health_cards'), 'tk_dd_id')
```

I tried

```
if "tk_dd_id" in collection:
        print("Found!")
```

> 'Collection' object is not iterable

type(collection)

```
if any("tk_dd_id" in s for s in collection):
        print("Found!")
```

> 'Collection' object is not iterable

```
type(collection)
<class 'pymongo.collection.Collection'>
```

[Find tuple of strings in string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47594122/find-tuple-of-strings-in-string-in-python)

Comment: any idea or solution about how to check string in pymongo collection ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question seems moot because you have to pass the collection name as a parameter to initial the `Collection` object. But if you must query the name you can do it with the `name` attribute:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pymongo.collection import Collection
from pymongo.database import Database

collection_name = "tk_dd_id"
collection = Collection(Database(MongoClient(host=['123234'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True, ssl=True, replicaset='mongomongo'), 'health_cards'), collection_name)

if "tk_dd_id" in collection_name:
    print("Found!")

if "tk_dd_id" in collection.name:
    print("Found!")
```

Comment: Thanks! I did not know we can access the `collection` name with `collection.name`. Do you know any documention about this because I could not find it :_)

Comment: https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection